# Babel aliases. WebStorm doesn't recognize sub-directories

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, alias, babeljs

I recently moved from `webpack` path aliases to [babel-plugin-module-resolved](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) as it integrates better with testing frameworks.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": false } ],
    "react",
    "stage-2",
    "flow"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "alias": {
        "static": "./static",
        "common": "./src/common",
        "data": "./src/data"
      }
    }],
    ["styled-jsx/babel", { "plugins": ["styled-jsx-plugin-sass"] }],
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

WebStorm automatically recognizes imports for `static/..` but can't resolve imports like `common/..` and `data/..`.

Is it possible to somehow instruct IDE about this configuration?

P.S. Right now I have `src` directory marked as *Resource Root* but this doesn't quite work as well.

Comment: Webstorm provides no support for  babel-plugin-module-resolved; there are dozens of similar plugins, each providing its own way to set up module resolution rules. You can hardly expect the IDE to support all these packages. as far as I can judge, marking src directory as Resource Root should help to resolve imports like common/.. and data/...

Comment: @lena Thanks that clears a lot! But how is that it somehow recognizes root directories like `static/..`?

Comment: it resolves paths relative to either current file or project/resource root. As `static/..` is a path from project root, it's recognized

Answer (score 8):

One option I've taken is to create a fake webpack file that creates the same aliases. Leaves an unnecessary file in your codebase, but fixes all the name resolution issues.

Example:
`webpack.junk.js`

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'static': path.resolve(__dirname, './static'),
      '@common': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/common'),
      '@data': path.resolve(__dirname, './src/data'),
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Following SimplyComplexable's solution (I can't comment on his reply, sorry), I've create a new `webpack.intellij.js` that loads the project's webpack config (`webpack.js`), reads the `.babelrc` file to generates the `resolve.alias` section for the exported config, then explicitly pointed IntelliJ to this file in the preferences:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.js');

const babelRc = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc').toString('utf8'));

const aliases = {};
for (let i = 0; i < babelRc.plugins.length; i+=1) {
  if (Array.isArray(babelRc.plugins[i]) && 
      babelRc.plugins[i][0] === 'module-resolver') {
    const a = babelRc.plugins[i][1].alias;
    for (const entry of Object.entries(a)) {
      aliases[entry[0]] = path.resolve(__dirname, entry[1]);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = merge(webpackConfig, {
  resolve: {
    alias: aliases
  }
});
```

This solution allows me to have the aliases configured in one single place (`.babelrc`) while still having IntelliJ recognise them :)